# ¿Como puedo darle formato a un documento word, desde MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que estoy generando un archivo word a partir de un boton que se encuentra en un formulario, en MS Visual Basic, genero el documento con el texto que yo le ingreso, se guarda y se abre automaticamente, mi pregunta es como le agrego formato a ese texto que estoy ingresando desde visual basic, por ejemplo: el hola mundo que estoy ingresando que salga con tipo de letra arial 20,con negrilla,centrado y si agrego otro texto mas, darle un formato diferente, tambien me gustaria saber como agregar una imagen desde ahi con alineacion centrada.

Aqui les adjunto mi codigo

```
'Se agrega la libreria para manejar aplicaciones word 
'Se agrega la referencia al proyecto de microsoft word object library
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btncrear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncrear.Click
        'Declara la variable.
        Dim objWD As Word.Application
        'Crea una nueva instancia de Word
        objWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'Agrega un nuevo documento en blanco
        objWD.Documents.Add()
        'Agrega Texto.
        objWD.Selection.TypeText("Hola mundo")
        'Guarda el documento
        objWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(FileName:="cotizacion.doc")
        'Declaramos la variable para abrir el documento y se le asigna el valor al objeto y especificamos el nombre del documento a abrir
        Dim archivoWord = objWD.Documents.Open(FileName:="cotizacion.doc")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Has intentado con `objWD.Selection.Font.Name = "Lucida Console"` por ejemplo?

Comment: Lo voy a intentar, ademas de el estilo de fuente, tienes el conocimiento de como se le cambia el tamaño y la alineacion tambien?

Comment: Intenta añadiendo a `objWD.Selection.Font` la propiedad que quieras, por ejemplo para tamaño `objWD.Selection.Font.Size=12`

Comment: Excelente amigo, por ultimo como podria dejar espacio entre cada texto que agregue y como alinear el texto que necesite al centro y si es posible cargar una imagen y alinearla igual.

Comment: Estaba pensando que para dejar espacio podria usar de nuevo el type text pero sin escribir nada en el, solo dejando espacios en blanco ejemplo: objWD.Selection.TypeText("        ") pero existe alguna propiedad que me evite hacer eso?

Comment: No estoy seguro,pero diría que no. Yo lo haría con `TypeText(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es usar la propiedad `Font` de `Selection` para modificar los parámetros que quieras de fuente. Por ejemplo:

```
objWD.Selection.Font.Name = "Lucida Console"
objWD.Selection.Font.Size=12
```